# Can you explain what this is (technobabble)?

Tags: dc, justice-league-crisis-on-two-earths

It's from **Justice League: Crisis on Two Earths**. Here's the quote:

> **Flash:** *How are we supposed to get inside again?*
>
> **Lex Luthor:** *Multi-frequency band, encryption analyzer-replicator pack.*
>
> **Flash:** *Some of us don't speak Star Trek*.
>
> **Lex Luthor:** *Think of it as a fancy garage-door opener.*

What exactly is a multi-frequency band, encryption analyzer-replicator pack? How does it work?

Comment: It's something that analyses and then replicates signals across a wide range of (presumably radio?) frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-Frequency Band = Basically a band is a "range", usually one frequency. For example, when you listen to the radio you are accessing 1 frequency. In this structure that would be called a Mono-frequency band, Broadband internet on the other hand refers both to the high capacity and that you are tapping into multiple frequencies.

Encryption analyzer-replicator = Means that it is scanning multiple frequencies and analyzing their signals... all signals are "encrypted" in some way technically. It is then able to duplicate them.

pack = it's a pack.

In terms of what it's talking about without knowing the context off hand. The devices is scanning all the frequencies, analyzing them, looking for the code for a door lock, and then replicating it to unlock the door. Basically it's the same concept as replicating someone's voice to get into a door that requires voice authentication.

Lex is just bad at naming things or trying to sound smarter than he is with the name...

However, this would not work in reality, because it has nothing to analyze in the first place, other than maybe the CPU humm, so it can't replicate to unlock whatever it's unlocking or decrypting and reproducing.

Comment: Btw, it was the hangar door outside the watchtower that Lex was trying to open.